# Excel - If two cells are greater than 0, than return the cell that is greater, if only one cell is greater than 0, than return that value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-statements

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now but I'm stuck on the `[value_if_false]` part and I feel like it's really simple but it's not coming to me.

So basically, trying to display the greater of two numbers (in specific cells) if both of them are numbers, but if only one of them is a number, then display that number.

```
=IF(AND(L10>0,L20>0),IF(L10>L20,L10,L20),)
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me what comes after the comma, help would be much appreciated, sorry if this has been asked before, couldn't find it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Just handle the exception case first:

```
=IF(AND(L10<=0,L20<=0),"",MAX(L10,L20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```
=MAX(L10,L20)
```

**Edit:**

An alternative, if you want blank returned when no numbers exist:

```
=IF(NOT(COUNT(A1:B1)),"",MAX(A1:B1))
```

Comment: If all arguments are blank, `MAX()` returns 0. Since the OP wants blank in that case, you'd still need an `IF()`, similar to Gary's Student's answer.

Comment: Or you could change the numberformat of the cell so that zero values aren't displayed. Although, I can't see the requirement for 'blank' in the OP.